# Absolute URL in 100s of files rewrite

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have created a dump from WayBack Machine so that a client can view his older site in order to create content plan. I loaded the backup to /~xxxxxxxx/ but as all the css and js in 100s of files are coded as follows:

```
<link href="/skins/FixedSize/styleSheets/style.css"
```

This results in 404 because the /~xxxxxx/ is ignored.

I have tried the following but no luck.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? /~xxxxxxxx/ [R=301,L]
```

I need a way to achieve this without modifying 470 HTML files.

Comment: Codes as follows: <link href="/skins/FixedSize/styleSheets/style.css"

Comment: _“I need a way to achieve this without modifying 470 HTML files.”_ - any halfway decent IDE should allow search & replace operations over the whole contents of a directory …

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you tried to express:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /~xxxxxxxx/$1 [END,QSA]
```

However you should be aware that this might be in conflict with other content you publish on that http host. There probably is a reason why you created that folder in the first place instead of using a hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT` which would have prevented the current issue. 
Which leads to an alternate suggestion: why don't you simply use a separate http host, so another "subdomain" as it is sometimes called?

Anyway, *if* you want to give above implementation a try, then please also note these additional hints:

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Unfortunately, it has not worked. When loading the URL I still get all CSS and JS with a 404 dueas the /~xxxxxxx/ is still missing.

Comment: OK, so you need to start debugging. That is something we cannot do for you. _You_ have access to your system and only you know your specific situation. The first step is to check if the implementation really is considered by the http server. So start monitoring your http server's error log file. Any entries? What changes if you place a definite syntax error in the configuration? Any change?

Comment: Here is some more information that will help including a link: http://uk2.ezeeinternet.net/~henedinburgh/ you can see the 404 in inspect element.

Comment: Sure, this demonstrates what you already said before. But it does not answer the questions I asked...

Comment: I have put random code into the htaccess file and I get server error which is correct. So the htaccess is being used.

Comment: OK, that is good. So the next step is to start monitoring the http server's error log file while making requests. What do you see?